# Can you be kicked for idling during the warmup in an official competitive match?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, competitive-gaming

I am wondering because I usually am warmed up, and I want to idle through warm up because of a computer problem.( don't be nosy please ) Will I still get kicked by console for no activity?

Answer (score 4):

Warmup, by definition, lasts for 5:00 in an official competitive match. When all players have connected, that timer drops to 1:00.

There are different possibilities for getting kicked, but idling doesn't get you kicked directly.  Your teammates can vote to kick you.

Reasons you can be kicked:

- You are kicked due to Steam issues (No Steam logon)
- You are votekicked by your teammates
- You are kicked for having damaged/killed too many teammates throughout the match.
- You trigger a VAC ban

Comment: Pretty sure you can get system kicked for idling an entire round.

Comment: Well that's not exactly what I mean, its just that... the console kicks you right?

Comment: What do you mean the console kicks you? The console doesn't determine whether or not you get kicked; its the game logic that determines if you get kicked.   The console is just a place to input commands, but it cannot kick you.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't be kicked from a competitive match for any reason unless your teammates vote you off.

Since competitive requires you to commit to playing the match it finds for you, it won't kick you for not moving — you have agreed to play. So if you idle during warmup, you're expected to return before the match starts.

Comment: if you idle in a competitive match you will get kicked and banned automatically

Comment: I've idled through an entire round plenty of times and I wasn't kicked. The system won't do that. If your teammates don't like it, they kick you.

Comment: @Adam You have to be idle more than a round.  It's more like 3 or 5 rounds of idle and yes, you will get auto kicked. That's considered intentional griefing, and you will be kicked and cooldowned if you don't reconnect before the reconnect timer runs out.

Comment: @Lo-Tan Then the rule must have been changed since I posted this answer.